# How to remove shade from cell and leave interiour color as is

Tags: vba, excel

I checked on the internet but could not find a solution. I the files we have mixed shaded and coloured cells, the shades need to be removed but the colours need to stay. I already have a range and want to fix it like below:

```
    Range(Cells(RowStart, ColStart), Cells(RowLast, ColLast)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

It does not work when I use .Pattern = xlNone or .TintAndShade = 0 in both options I loose the cell interior color. Please advice

Comment: Don't post that as a comment - many people won't read it. It is 100% acceptable (and encouraged) to answer your own question when you've found the answer.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan just did

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer that does the trick for me, I leave the question so others can benifit from it. This code does the trick for me:

```
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after I double checked the solution on a real used sheet instead of my test file. I saw that also the default light grey standard cell borders are not there anymore. So I am not happy yet. Who has a solution for me?